# Maximum Likelihood Estimate of Laplacian distribution with one parameter $\sigma$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, self-learning, variance, mean-square-error

Given variant of laplacian distribution

$p(x|\sigma) = \frac{1}{2 \sigma} e^{\frac{|x|}{\sigma}}, \sigma > 0$ with parameter  $\sigma$

I got MLE for $\sigma$ as $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|}{n}$

calculating

$E[|x|] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\sigma} |x| e^{\frac{-|x|}{\sigma}} dx \\ = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sigma} |x| e^{\frac{-|x|}{\sigma}} dx = \sigma$

$E[|x|^2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\sigma} |x|^2 e^{\frac{-|x|}{\sigma}} dx \\ = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sigma} |x|^2 e^{\frac{-|x|}{\sigma}} dx = 2\sigma^2$

$\text {var} (|x_i|) = E[|x_i|^2] - (E[|x|])^2 = 2\sigma^2 - \sigma^2 = \sigma^2$

Variance($\hat \sigma$) = variance ($ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|}{n}$) =\frac{1}{n} $Var(|x_i|) =\frac{1}{n} \sigma^2$

Bias($\hat \sigma$) = $E[\hat \sigma] - \sigma = E[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|}{n}] - \sigma = (1/n)n \sigma = \sigma $

Now MSE($\hat \sigma$) = $Bias^2 + \text {variance} = \frac{1}{n} \sigma^2 $

May i know is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bias is not correct.  Notice that unless every $X_i = 0$, the sum $$\hat \sigma = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i| > 0.$$  So the calculation of the expectation is not $0$, because the estimator $\hat \sigma$ is almost surely strictly positive.

In order to compute the bias, you must compute the expectation of the absolute value of a single observation; i.e., $$\operatorname{E}[|X|] = \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \frac{|x|}{2\sigma} e^{-|x|/\sigma} \, dx = \int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x}{\sigma} e^{-x/\sigma} \, dx.$$  Then use the linearity of expectation to compute $\operatorname{E}[\hat \sigma]$.

To compute the variance, also begin from a single observation:  $$\operatorname{E}[|X|^2] = \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \frac{|x|^2}{2\sigma} e^{-|x|/\sigma} \, dx.$$  Then $$\operatorname{Var}[|X|] = \operatorname{E}[|X|^2] - \operatorname{E}[|X|]^2,$$ and then, by independence of the individual observations, $$\operatorname{Var}[\hat \sigma] = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}[|X_i|].$$

Comment: sir can you pls verify now. I am getting the estimator as unbiased!

Comment: @NascimentodeCos The bias calculation is now correct, but the variance calculation is still not correct because the variance of the estimator should decrease as the sample size gets larger, but yours does not.  Note the last equation in my answer.

Comment: Sir i got it. variance should be $\sigma^2/n$ , But if estimtor variance is function of sample size, then in all variances of estimates should be function of n (sample size) and that too in denomintor right? But i read estimator means just function of  random sample.

Comment: sir i think this is true only in case of consistent estimator? But no where it is mentioned so. Expectation is zero and variance happned to be $\sigma^2/n$ which means variance goes to zero for large sample size. Is that we need to assume that all estimators are by default consistent?

Comment: @NascimentodeCos Whether the estimator's variance is a function of sample size depends on the estimator and its sampling distribution.  For instance, $|X_1|$ is an estimator of $\sigma$, but it is not a very good estimator, because it discards a lot of information about the sample.  And we can see it lacks desirable asymptotic properties for this reason; the amount of information is the same whether or not the sample size is $1$, $10$, or $1000$, because it ignores all but the first observation.

Comment: thank you sir .....